# Are there any gotchas reinstalling Windows 7 on a Mac with Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, reinstall

I'm reinstalling Windows 7 on my Mac. Are there any gotchas that I should be aware of during the process, or should the process be straightforward?

My current plan is:

1. Copy everything important from my Windows partition before the reinstall.
2. Destroy the current Windows partition.
3. Use Bootcamp to install Windows using the same process I used to install it the first time.

Comment: With this kind of question, if the answer is, "There's nothing to be worried about," I'm fine with that being posted.

Comment: I think you got everything sorted. But one thing I always ask before wiping: Are you sure you copied everything that you care about (whether important or not)? Data? Documents? Pictures? Bookmarks? And then ask yourself again, are you sure you copied everything? Reason being that almost every time I do this to any of our client (even to myself) I will come back and say "I forgot to copy some stuff" ... so yes. Just ask yourself again, are you sure you copied everything you care about? Beyond that, its fine. Just delete the Windows partition (on #2) and re-run the Bootcamp process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The process you detailed seems fine.**

I did something similar when upgrading my Boot Camp from Windows 7 to Windows 8; I wanted a fresh start so I backed up my data, erased the partition and installed Windows 8. It all went fine: no change to my Mac partition or anything else.

As Darius mentioned, make sure that you are copying **everything** that you need from your Windows partition before destroying it.

If you have a second hard drive, or space on your Mac partition, it might be worth making a full disk image of the partition that you can mount if you need any data, and delete it once you know you have everything. Go to Disk Utility, select the Boot Camp partition and click New Image in the toolbar or press File → New → Disk Image from "Boot Camp".